# Function that returns MAX OR MIN dates based on ID count

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, partition, dense-rank

I have a task in SQL Server where I need to return the RESULT_DATE column using ID, PRODUCT_ID and DATE columns. Task criteria:

1. If DATE column is filled once for each PRODUCT_ID then I need to return the only date (like for PRODUCT_ID 1 and 3). Let`s say its MIN date.
2. If DATE column is filled more than one time (like for PRODUCT_ID 2)  then I need to return the next filled DATE row.

**Data:**

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (
    ID INT,
    PRODUCT_ID INT,
    [DATE] DATETIME
    )
INSERT #temp (ID, PRODUCT_ID, DATE) VALUES 
(1, 1,  '2008-04-24 00:00:00.000'),
(2, 1,  NULL),
(3, 2,  '2015-12-09 00:00:00.000'),
(4, 2,  NULL),
(5, 2,  NULL),
(6, 2,  '2022-01-01 13:06:45.253'),
(7, 2,  NULL),
(8, 2,  '2022-01-19 13:06:45.253'),
(9, 3,  '2018-04-25 00:00:00.000'),
(10,3,  NULL),
(11,3,  NULL)
```

| ID | PRODUCT_ID | DATE | **RESULT_DATE** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2008-04-24 00:00:00.000 | **2008-04-24 00:00:00.000** |
| 2 | 1 | *NULL* | **2008-04-24 00:00:00.000** |
| 3 | 2 | 2015-12-09 00:00:00.000 | **2022-01-01 13:06:45.253** |
| 4 | 2 | *NULL* | **2022-01-01 13:06:45.253** |
| 5 | 2 | *NULL* | **2022-01-01 13:06:45.253** |
| 6 | 2 | 2022-01-01 13:06:45.253 | **2022-01-19 13:06:45.253** |
| 7 | 2 | *NULL* | **2022-01-19 13:06:45.253** |
| 8 | 2 | 2022-01-19 13:06:45.253 | **2022-01-19 13:06:45.253** |
| 9 | 3 | 2018-04-25 00:00:00.000 | **2018-04-25 00:00:00.000** |
| 10 | 3 | *NULL* | **2018-04-25 00:00:00.000** |
| 11 | 3 | *NULL* | **2018-04-25 00:00:00.000** |

I have tried different techniques, for example using `LEAD` and `LAG` SQL function combinations. The latest script: (However, still not working)

```
SELECT 
COALESCE(DATE,
        CAST(
            SUBSTRING(
                MAX(CAST(DATE AS BINARY(4)) + CAST(DATE AS BINARY(4))) OVER ( PARTITION BY PRODUCT_ID ORDER BY DATE ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
            ,5,4) 
        AS INT)
    ) AS RESULT_DATE,
*
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: Why are you converting the [Date] column to Binary then to substring then back to date? Please don't use reserved words (Date) as column names or table names (TABLE). I'm not sure your code actually runs.

Comment: If you provide sample data as DDL+DML you make it much easier for people to assist.

Comment: Hello @SteveFord . Placing DATE column name in [ ] will do the trick. However, the code is not running properly as mentioned.

Comment: @KonstantinsKovalovs I know you can use [] to escape these reserved words, but it really does make your code much harder to read and understand so should still not use reserved words. Why are you converting a date to a binary adding it to itself then converting to an INT then using in a COALESCE it makes no sense at all. As Dale K mentioned please add CREATE TABLE Statement, some inserts to insert test data, the query you are trying, any errors you receive and what your expected results are.

Comment: @SteveFord I added the script! The expected results are visible in the RESULTS_DATA column :)

Comment: @lptr This is what i needed! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE, Select all rows with a non-NULL Date giving each a row_number, then use a second CTE to fetch all rows from the first CTE equivalent to the date with the largest row number per product_id that is less than 3. Finally join this CTE to the original table to supply the 2nd Date to each row:

**Set Up**

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (
    ID INT,
    PRODUCT_ID INT,
    MyDATE DATETIME
)
INSERT #temp (ID, PRODUCT_ID, MyDate) 
VALUES 
    (1, 1,  '2008-04-24 00:00:00.000'),
    (2, 1,  NULL),
    (3, 2,  '2015-12-09 00:00:00.000'),
    (4, 2,  NULL),
    (5, 2,  NULL),
    (6, 2,  '2022-01-01 13:06:45.253'),
    (7, 2,  NULL),
    (8, 2,  '2022-01-19 13:06:45.253'),
    (9, 3,  '2018-04-25 00:00:00.000'),
    (10,3,  NULL),
    (11,3,  NULL);
```

**Query:**

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT ID, Product_ID, MyDate, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Product_ID ORDER BY Id) AS rn
    from #temp
    WHERE MyDate IS NOT NULL
),
CTE2
AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM CTE C1
    WHERE C1.rn < 3 
        AND
        C1.rn = 
            (SELECT MAX(rn) FROM CTE WHERE Product_Id = C1.Product_Id AND rn<3)
)
SELECT T.Id, T.Product_Id, T.MyDate, C.MyDate As Result_date
FROM #temp T
INNER JOIN CTE2 C
    ON T.Product_Id = C.Product_Id
ORDER BY T.Id;
```

**Results:**

```
Id  Product_Id  MyDate                   Result_Date
1   1           2008-04-24 00:00:00.000  2008-04-24 00:00:00.000
2   1           NULL                     2008-04-24 00:00:00.000
3   2           2015-12-09 00:00:00.000  2022-01-01 13:06:45.253
4   2           NULL                     2022-01-01 13:06:45.253
5   2           NULL                     2022-01-01 13:06:45.253
6   2           2022-01-01 13:06:45.253  2022-01-01 13:06:45.253
7   2           NULL                     2022-01-01 13:06:45.253
8   2           2022-01-19 13:06:45.253  2022-01-01 13:06:45.253
9   3           2018-04-25 00:00:00.000  2018-04-25 00:00:00.000
10  3           NULL                     2018-04-25 00:00:00.000
11  3           NULL                     2018-04-25 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however not quite as in the result example. For Product_id Resul_Date columns for Product_Id should be:

```3 2022-01-01 13:06:45.253
4 2022-01-01 13:06:45.253
5 2022-01-01 13:06:45.253
6 2022-01-19 13:06:45.253
7 2022-01-19 13:06:45.253
8 2022-01-19 13:06:45.253```

Comment: @KonstantinsKovalovs The results exactly match the results shown in the question, I have reformatted the results to make it clearer. They also match your comments so not sure what you mean